# AWS api_gateway custom authorizer: Whats the ID of my custom authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-api-gateway

Im implementing custom authentication using AWS api gateway and Lambda functions. In Chalice documentation, its stated that I need a `authorizer_id` to link the lambda function with the desired authentication.

```
@app.route('/authenticated', methods=['GET'], authorization_type='CUSTOM', authorizer_id='ab12cd')
def authenticated():
    return {"secure": True}
```

**Question:** Where can I find the `authorizer_id` for my custom authorizer?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID can be found in the "breadcrumbs" of the AWS web console (IDs are censored out, you get the idea):

[image]